# Strings in classes // C++

Tags: c++, string, class, function

I am new to C++ and troubling with strings in classes

Date.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Date::Date(int day,int month,int year )
{
    setDate(day,month,year);
}

void Date::setDate(int day,int month,int year)
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}

string Date::printIt()
{
    std::stringstream res;

    res<<this->day<<"/";
    res<<this->month<<"/";
    res<<this->year;

    return res.str;
}

Date operator+(const Date &date,int day)
{
    Date newDate(date.day,date.month,date.month);

    newDate.day += day;

    if(newDate.day > 30)
    {
        newDate.day%=30;
        newDate.month+=1;

        if(newDate.month>=12)
        {
            newDate.month%=30;
            newDate.year+=1;
        }
    }

    return newDate;
}
```

Date.h:

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H 

using namespace std;

class Date
{
private:
    int day,month,year;

    Date(){}

public:
    Date(int day,int month,int year);

    void setDate(int day,int month,int year);
    string printIt();

    friend Date operator+(const Date &date, int day);
};


#endif
```

The problem is `printIt()` function. Visual Studio says that declarations are incompatible. When I change the type of function to `int` the problem disappears but why there is a problem with `string`s?

Comment: I don't see your problem with strings?  Is the code sample showing the problem?

Comment: You have to include `<string>` before you use it. The compiler reads the file line by line and will not look ahead for you.

Comment: Never, ever, put `using namespace` in a header, and as the previous comment says, you need to `#include <string>` in `Date.h`, and then `std::string printIt();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with your include order:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

You're including `Date.h`, which contains `string`, before you include the header that defines `string`.

It should be

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"
```

or better yet, include `string` directly in the header. This is so you don't have to worry about the order in other `cpp` files where you might include the header.

Comment: You shouldn't have to rely on the order with which you include header files... prefer the second solution that you provided.

Answer (score 5):

If `Date.h` is going to use the `string` class, then the necessary header files have to be included either *before* `Date.h` or *in* `Date.h`.

Comment: thanks so much for your concern and also thanks to others too. The problem was that.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to the `str` member function rather than a `string`. Call `str()` for this to work

```
string Date::printIt()
{
    ...

    return res.str();//call str method
}
```

Also you need to move the `#include <string>` to the header file since `string` is used for the return type of `printIt`.

Comment: Does res.str denote a method pointer? Isn't res::str the pointer? I think that res.str would give a different error - might just be a typo.

Comment: Well... if you'd have compiled you would have seen that that's not the issue. I mean it was an issue, but not the cause to his problem. Regardless, you're right, not worth -1, but also not +1 since it doesn't answer the question. This would have been better as a comment.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There are obviously 2 issues here, I really doubt that is a typo unless the OP decided to type everything in by hand instead of just a simple copy&paste from the editor. The answer is a combinations of Davids and mine :), I will add that to mine but +1 to Davids

Answer (score 0):

Reorder you headers so that the string type declaration appears before Date.h

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Date.h"
```